# Alternative reward levels to “Gold, Silver, Bronze”?

Tags: gamification, alternatives

I am looking for an easily identifiable awarding scheme, but without using metals, specifically "Gold, Silver, Bronze".

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What is wrong with gold, silver and bronze? The context in which you are going to be using this may be helpful so we can cater the suggestion to that situation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Gold, Silver and Bronze, I am just looking for alternative awarding schemes. For example someone here has suggested different coloured ribbons. I was wondering if there were any more?

Comment: Solutions to this issue may be too context-dependent to make the question useful to others.  For example, on an airline site you could progress from glider to biplane to jumbo jet, but those categories aren't likely to be useful outside that context.

Comment: I would like the awarding scheme to be easily identifiable - pretty much everybody knows that Gold, Silver and Bronze are often awarded, and everybody knows their value in relationship to each other. Is there anything else like this?

Comment: Gold, Silver and Bronze is an existing award scheme that works in any context (any context I can think of). It's easily identifiable. It has universal acceptance. Is there another award scheme like this, or similar? If not completely universal, near or approaching a universal acceptance? I feel like if I gave anyone here the context I am using I wouldn't get a universal awards scheme like "Gold, Silver, Bronze", instead I would get something very specific to the context I am working in - I dont want something specific to one context, I want something that is more universal than that.

Comment: Are you looking for an award system that implies simply order, value, or both? For example, "First", "Second", "Third" implies order but not value. "Gold", "Silver", and "Bronze" implies an order that's based on value.

Comment: Easily recognisable depends on your audience e.g. "Ace, King, Queen, Jack" or "King, Queen, Rook, Bishop, Knight" are raking schemes for card and chess players respectively.

Comment: @Jayfang I agree with your general point, but your examples are problematic: There are card games where the order is different, e.g. Ace counting as 1 or Ten being higher than King. The same applies to card suits. In chess, bishop and knight are often considered as being of equal value. Kings topping Queens is also kinda sexist.

Comment: As usual, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_of_precious_substances) has something to contribute to the matter.

Comment: It's worth noting that Silver is better than Gold if the Olympics are attacked by werewolves.

Comment: @bjb568: Their order is not inherently clear; conventions vary a lot between countries and cultures. See, for example, school marks, which are sometimes numbers, sometimes letters, sometimes counting upwards and something counting downwards. **However**, if the number is expressed as the count of a "tangible object", it may work again - e.g. coins or diamonds - the numbers may work again, because then the inherent metaphor "the more, the better" starts working.

Comment: Depending on your context, you could use a single rating. You're either "special" with a cool icon by your name or "normal" without.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It should be obvious enough with higher ranks being higher on the page, for example 3 bars left to right with 1st in the tallest middle bar or a list of rankings like SE's reputation legues.

Comment: I vote for *Titanium* and *Unobtianium* to be added to the main three.

Comment: I worked with one company in which the marketing department had decided that our default system of indicating customer priority as Gold/Silver/Bronze was making a value judgement. 

So if a customer found out (and in theory they could) that they had been marked as Bronze, then they might feel upset about their value to the company. Even though the company had marked them objectively as Bronze because they were not high value. 
We swapped icons/text to a industry specific variant; something like Sun/Planet/Moon

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The struggle for a good top-rating system is...nightmarish. I've gone through it several times, and agree that gold/silver/bronze isn't particularly great. Here are some alternatives:

- Smiley faces: Special rankings can be given with any number of different smiley faces using either custom or existing emoji. Unfortunately, ranking those individually is a challenge.
- Jewels: Diamonds, Rubies, Sapphires, etc. Follows the same as metals however. Not as recognizable.
- Stars: star ratings are typically considered big, but if it isn't a rating, then you can easily give 3, 4, or 5 stars as awards, where more stars is better. The amount doesn't really matter (1/2/3 or 3/4/5 work equally well, though the latter begs the question where do 1 & 2 stars go?)
- Custom: Obviously the hardest, but depending on the context, potentially the most relevant too. If it's a halloween game, for example, instead of stars you could use skulls. If it's a medical forum, then high-ranking members may be displayed with a stethoscope, for example.

Play around with it and see what you like. If you don't like gold/silver/bronze, then don't use it for sure. Because that's going to drive you crazy for a long time, and if you're the one who has to use the thing you're building...

Comment: Instead of 3->5 stars, you could always just have 1->3 stars.  Works well enough for restaurants - see Michelin Stars

Comment: The 1->3 star design pattern works both if a user is being judged against other users, or against themselves. Mobile gaming relies heavily on this pattern to give players an indication of how they perform on individual levels (ex: Angry Birds)

Comment: Why just not `Red Orange/Yellow Green?` (colours of traffic lights?)

Comment: @jbutler483 traffic light colours may work, for sure. Even more so over here, in Portugal, as those are our flag colours, so they usually feel nice and comfortable. But as to question at hand it may not be a suitable replacement. Gold/Silver/Bronze are "degrees of goodness", they all have a positive tone (bronze medal is fine, right?), while Green/Yellow/Red has some negative connotation for Red (stop!) and only Green is really positive

Comment: There is irony in the post editors receiving bronze badges for this answer.

Comment: Of note on the star designs, bear in mind the stars need not be arranged linearly, depending on your UI layout. One star obviously has no dimension, and two stars have to be next to each other, but 3 stars can be arranged in a triangle (for either 1/2/3 or 3/4/5), and in a 3/4/5 scheme the 4 stars can be arranged in a square and 5 in a pentagon. Of course linear always remains an option if that fits your layout better :)

Comment: A benefit to the star-based system is that they have greater accessibility. While you *can* carefully tune your gold/silver/bronze colors to maintain easy differentiability even for colorblind or low-sight users, counting stars is easier for either class of user than trying to differentiate color.

Comment: If you were to go with the jewel theme, you could improve ranking differentiability by increasing the number of sides  of the jewel on higher ranks, and keeping the colors in spectral order (e.g. ruby, topaz, citrine, emerald, sapphire, amethyst, diamond). The side count can be differentiated by a fully colorblind user, though less than the star counts for low-sight users, while fully sighted users will quickly learn to correlate the spectral association with rank.

Comment: If having icons is no real requirement, you could have custom application-specific titles. To quote [Graham Nelson's "The Craft of the Adventure" (2nd Ed)](http://mirror.ifarchive.org/if-archive/info/Craft.Of.Adventure.pdf), from section Scoring in chapter 6:
> Another amusing touch is that ranks tend to be named for the player's profession in the game - so, a musician might begin as "Novice" and rise through "Second Violinist" to "Conductor". One of the wittiest is in the detective game 'Sherlock', where the lowest rank - of zero achievement - is "Chief Superintendent of Scotland Yard".

Comment: The [OneWorld alliance of airlines](http://www.oneworld.com/ffp/oneworld-benefits) uses Ruby < Sapphire < Emerald for its frequent flyer cards. Although they're always listed and displayed in that order, it isn't immediately obvious which are better. [British Airways](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/executive-club/tiers-and-benefits?source=MNVEXC1_tiers_and_benefits&link=main_nav&link=main_nav) uses Blue < Bronze < Silver < Gold; Blue is one of the colours associated with BA -  the colour of part of the logo and until recently plane interiors (now black)

Answer (score 21):

Since nobody referred to alternatives to metals on the level of cultural philosophy:

I think you are right that gold, silver and bronze are outdated as a universal symbol of rewarding.
As we tend to redefine characteristic *values* of human individuals as mental properties  rather than material properties, I suggest discussing symbols of human evolution itself rather than the mentioned materials:

[image: Fire icon]**1. fire**

[image: Book as Printing icon]**2. printing**

[image: Internet icon]**3. internet**

…would be my first intuition here. Don't you agree they also make up a neat triple of icons?

Comment: I think "...what" adequately sums up my reaction to this idea.

Comment: what an original idea! i never considered using human achievements as an award system. im not sure if this is as universal as gold, silver and bronze, but in my book you get points for thinking outside the box!

Comment: where's the wheel?  You just gotta add "the wheel"! :)

Comment: I think this example would be ineffective because it's not intuitive. The chosen icons are actually vague, and unless all the icons are shown besides the awarded one, the user can't judge how well or poorly s/he's done. Jayfang is joking about there not being a wheel icon, but that's part of the problem: if the user can't see or correctly anticipate the entire system, then an icon on its own is meaningless. The constructs are open to opinion, too; the Internet is more sophisticated than fire, but is it universally seen as being more important?

Comment: @TimHuynh especially since the references are taken from a logarithmically distributed timeline of the universe.

Comment: There may be a nugget of possibility in this, though. Ape -> Caveman -> Homo sapien? If the icons were drawn well it would be pretty recognizable.

Comment: @wavemode Some people, myself included, find it offensive that people say we evolved from apes. I'd have issues with a system like that.

Comment: @Mazyod Yeah, you're probably right (and the thought had occurred to me), just thought it'd be an interesting possibility.

Comment: @Mazyod I'm not sure if this is relevant in this discussion, I am not catering for people who are highly insecure and sensitive towards modern thinking, this is a website after all. The same scientific process that gave us the Internet and computing in general is the same scientific process that has proven we and Apes come from a common ancestor, I dont know why you'd be OK with one result of scientific endeavor and yet take issue with another.

Comment: @Jimmery It's how people are... Accept it or not is your choice, but marking that such people exist is relevant. It's not "catering", it's just being considerate. I have no idea why you are bringing up your thought process here, **that** is irrelevant.

Comment: I am not being considerate to those who are offended by provable facts in the exact same way I am not being considerate towards people who believe the world is flat and get offended by the symbol of a Globe. It is simply impractical and illogical to try and be considerate towards everyone, so instead I am going to be considerate to the vast majority of free thinking, logical people who can follow simple evidence to its obvious conclusion. Hell, even the Pope wouldn't be offended by the idea of Man evolving from Apes: http://beta.slashdot.org/story/209109

Comment: @Jimmery you don't get it. No one really cares what you think or will do, hence, is irrelevant. You're trying to say I am wrong, or convince me, or what exactly?

Comment: I like how you are telling others people that "no one really cares what you think", when you have just been telling other people your own personal opinions on what offends you. So think of your own quote next time you feel the urge to express your own backwards viewpoint on the world. No one really cares what you think. And if I am trying to do anything here, its to tell you that we don't need reminding that easily offended idiots exist in this world. I am done here, but please feel free to cry further if it makes you feel better.

Comment: My first reaction to this answer was "Huh?" But then I saw that Jimmery liked it. And then it made sense when I started stalking his [Arqade profile](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/36737/jimmery), especially in light of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/170775). It's perfectly logical why you would want to avoid metals for reward levels, since they would be confused with specie currency. In this context, you may have given a brilliant answer to a truly crappy, vague question.

Comment: @Jimmery: For one, the hypothesizing done to create models is scientifically *extremely* different from the process that gave us the internet. As in, hardly comparable to be honest. Where one is designing, applying and testing models the other is just trying to design models that fit observed facts. Humans evolving from a common ancestors with apes *does* fit the observed facts quite well, however that does not make it a fact. One can both agree on the observations and make use of products that have been designed based on the hypothesized model, without agreein on the model

Comment: which is likely the case for a lot of things you're using, such as language itself. Either way, getting back to your evolution idea, what you call 'easily offendable people' are a part of a far larger group that would likely get distracted by such a model. Not becaues they would be offended, but simply because the UX experience would be sub par as they get distracted from the intended meaning.

Answer (score 21):

In some situations, something similar to army ranking can be used:

[image]

Comment: I' thinking of the old video game, G.O.R.F.  The ranks included "Space Cadet", "Space Colonel" and 5 or 6 others.

Comment: Ahh brings back memories of [Cannon Fodder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannon_Fodder_%28series%29#mediaviewer/File:Cannon_Fodder_screenshot.png)

Answer (score 14):

<sub>*Note: This is my second reply, and I'm not rep-whoring.  So please choose one (or neither) of my suggestions...*</sub>

---

For kids, you can use something similar to The Potato Head as a motivator and progression indicator:

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 13):

My 2¢ are summed up by the Clash of Clans League hierarchy:

[image]

Not necessarily a shield with stuff on it, but a very "basic" design, that looks meaner and cooler for higher levels. Even if it is a ■ -> ⬟ -> ★ or something like that.

Comment: Your middle example icon is not supported.

Comment: @TylerH by your browser?

Comment: Yes. You should use unicode icons that are supported without the need for custom or additional plugins.

Comment: I think this system would be usable, provided that you sell of the icons at once; ie, your awarded icon is bright and the others are grayed out. At least this way, you can gauge how well you've done relative to the other milestones.

Comment: For the curious, the shapes are square -> pentagon -> star

Comment: Wow, extending the established bronze-silver-gold scale **above gold** when it’s used for ranks (i.e. 1st place or class) and not anniversaries (i.e. 50 years) is just stupid, much like A++ energy ratings or AAA credit ratings or DDDD bra cups or volume controls going to 11. @Mazyod’s suggestion is sound however.

Comment: @TylerH FWIW, it displays fine in Firefox and in Internet Explorer, without any need for custom fonts, plug-ins, add-ons, anything.

Comment: @hvd it actually does *not* display fine in Firefox. http://i.imgur.com/wJhLQDy.jpg

Comment: @TylerH Okay, then it isn't just browser-dependent, it's also OS-dependent. How many different browsers and OS's should someone preview their answer in before posting?

Comment: @hvd Just one is fine; just use a *web*-friendly encoding like I mentioned before.

Comment: @TylerH So out of the tens of thousands of Unicode symbols, we're supposed to magically know which of those work on every current browser and OS. Sorry, but that's not something you can expect of anyone. If I had posted this answer, I might very well also have used this particular symbol, I would have known that I hadn't installed anything in particular to make this particular symbol work, so I would have no way of knowing that it isn't "web-friendly" for any reasonable definition of "web-friendly".

Comment: @hvd UTF-8 has been supported by all web browsers for *years*. And yes, creating content for the web often comes with the requirement that you just "know" what works. See, well, the entire field of web development or any programming language.

Comment: @TylerH Please stop, you’re embarrassing yourself. The character is correctly and “_web_-friendly” encoded, with UTF-8. It’s just your setup that’s missing a font with support for this particular character. Happens. Also, this is off-topic here.

Comment: @Crissov Then that should've been clarified in the earlier comments. And if your comment is off-topic, why post it and then remark on that fact?

Comment: +1 for the square, pentagon, star idea. Also @TylerH: the pentagon has been in unicode since March 2008. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b1f/index.htm

Comment: -1 because I've wasted way too much money on CoC. +1 because that's not a good reason to downvote a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: @JasonC -1 for your unrelated answer, I guess. +1 because that too isn't a reasonable answer. We square?

Comment: @Mazyod Even Steven!

Answer (score 8):

If you're going to a use a multi-tiered award system, ask yourself,

**Can the user (a) *see* every tier or (b) accurately *predict* every tier?**

If the answer to either (a) or (b) is "No" then any award that you give to the user will probably be meaningless to him/her. The core function of giving an award is to give feedback: people want to know if they've performed well or poorly and, just as importantly, how well or how poorly they've performed.

It's difficult to evaluate my performance based on the the award you've given to me if I can't figure out its value relative to other tiers, assuming there are other tiers. As a solution, you could show all tiers and only highlight the one that applies to me. Or you could stay with the so-called boring but widely understood bronze-silver-gold scheme.

*Please* don't try to reinvent the proverbial wheel. That's how usability problems usually happen: people go against the grain because of personal preference. If you absolutely must introduce novelty, then do it like the trophy system on the PlayStation Network: have unique badges and names for each accomplishment, but assign a bronze, silver, gold, or platinum trophy to each one. That way there's freshness and familiarity (usability) to each achievement.

That's the problem I have the gamification trend in general. Badges and icons that have no pre-existing meaning or practical value need to go.

Comment: Although similar recommendation have been given, it's valid, and I'll +1 to get this post out of negative. Cannot make it gold, though :-(

Answer (score 6):

Think of this as a data visualization problem: The awards make up an ordinal scale, where a "[particular value has no significance beyond its ability to establish a ranking over a set of data points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data)". You need to show one is greater or less than the other.

Gold, Silver and Bronze refer to the Olympic medals and other sports. Arguably they are not a sure thing depending on culture or color blindness factors. They are also limited because the scheme breaks down after three ranks. You might need more than three winners. With that said, if you are designing something Olympic/sports related your users might understand or expect the medal symbols.

**Consider your users.** They have the ultimate privilege of accepting or rejecting your design choice. And always include a key somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

There’s often a three-tier ranking system that can be deduced from the setting of the site or application. You can even have more symbolic slots than that. The sports medal metaphor is quite well understood, tough, but the different metals, especially yellowish gold and brownish bronze may be hard to distinguish. Note that this base system has been adapted and augmented elsewhere, e.g. in anniversaries (‘diamond’), credit cards (‘black’) and record sales (‘platinum’).

You can try size: big, medium, small. Bigger is always better (except when it’s not). Empty to filled also works with a variety of shapes, e.g. moon phases (although this one has a mirrored medial step).

Applying arbitrary meaning to colors is always complicated and prone to failure, but when combined with positional cues as in traffic lights it may work: top/left green, middle yellow/orange, bottom/right red. A combination with otherwise monochrome symbols works slightly better, although the signs may have different meaning in context: green plus, orange/yellow circle/disc, red minus.
Like all these, arrows and thumbs do not indicate top three but rather show best, rest and worst: (pointing) up, sideways, down.

In hierarchical systems, e.g. military and academia, there are familiar ranks of people, elsewhere important items or services may be ranked frequently. Those may not have mnemonic visuals, e.g. classes in trains, ships and planes are either plain ordinal numeric or use rather arbitrary names.

[image: Human evolution]

Comment: Not all ranking systems have three tiers, so it's potentially a mistake to assume that the user will assume, correctly or not, that they've been awarded a representation in a three-tier system.

Comment: @TimHuynh That’s true of course. Some of the options I listed above at least have rather unambiguous top and low ends, the number of intermediate steps being uncertain. The question still misses some clarifications to clearly identify the type of desired scale. It’s quite possible, Jimmery would gladly be able to use more tiers or have non-achievers (i.e. below bronze) unmarked.

Comment: I think the ape on the left deserves an upvote by itself :-D

Answer (score 4):

If this is some kind of award, I like RIBBONS - while most people agree the blue ribbon comes first/best there are cultural differences for the other places.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_ribbon

Comment: *"while most people agree the blue ribbon comes first/best..."* that is probably more culturally specific (US-centric really) than you are aware of. In the UK for instance there is no use of blue ribbons in that sense, and there certainly isn't any ranking implied by a ribbon colour. If anything ribbons are used as symbols of charity and causes; different colours representing different charities.

Comment: I agree with @JonW for this being very US-centric. I'm from central Europe, never heard of ribbons meant as expressing an award.

Comment: Yes the link I posted covers all that.

Answer (score 3):

How about a grading scheme like:

- SS
- S
- A
- B
- C
- D
- F

I have seen this used in quite a few video games of Japanese origin. Leaving out the S's could be more recognizable, as most people are aware of letter grades.

Or you could use multiple stars or emblems like:

- *****
- ****
- ***
- **
- *

This kind of system has been used for reviews/scores/etc. numerous times.

Comment: The problem with the first system is that "S" and "SS" probably won't be understood by non-gamers. Also, non-Americans might not understand why the system goes from "D" to "F" or vice versa. The stars system is more intuitive, assuming that it's clear whether the max-rating is five stars or 10 stars.

Comment: There’s also the single-star rating with filled prongs, i.e. 0–5 for pentagram and 0–6 for star of David. It has the advantages of clearly showing the upper and lower limits and having a square bounding box, but may be less  easy and quick to scan and compare.

Comment: Nice DMC reference.

Comment: In some parts of the world, *SS* has an extremely negative historical connotation.

Comment: You could change SS and S to AAA and AA (like in DDR).

Comment: I don't think S and SS are typical bra sizes. Oh, wait. These are grades.

Comment: @TimHuynh speaking of which, what do they stand for?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper in other parts of the world, people don't automatically make assumptions from TWO LETTERS.

Comment: @haneefmubarak: I didn't claim anyone was making assumptions. I was just pointing out that the two particular letters *SS* are not simply "not inherently understood", but downright *counterintuitive* as a representation of "very good" in some regions. Personally, I do think it is ridiculous to have simply combinations of a few letters totally "spoiled" by one unfortunate use in the past, but that's simply the way it is.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ah well that's fine then. Thanks for the explanation :-)

Comment: @haneefmubaraks In some video games (eg, the Resident Evil series), an "S" ranking stands for "Superior."

Answer (score 3):

I would consider (since it's 'gameification'), something like:

[image: this]

Or Ranks such as

1. Master/Merlin
2. Wizard
3. Apprentice

Another possible ranking could be:

1. King
2. Prince
3. Jester

There are just so many Three tier ranking systems, that it's quite hard to choose one!

Angry Birds uses Stars, for example.

Even a traffic light system might work:

[image: here]

Comment: I would have guessed that Wizard is above Master.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann edited :P

Comment: Re: traffic light - which color denotes best performance?

Comment: green (for go) @BobJarvis

Answer (score 3):

- The good, the bad, the very bad.
- The cat, the puma, the lion.
- Much, muchier, the muchiest.
- One cup of unbelievable bravery, one bottle of unbelievable bravery, one gallon of ubelievable bravery.
- Pass, Distinction, Merit
- Pale , glossy, shiny.
- Screwdriver, wrench, hammer
- Tenor, alto, bass
- Nothing. We all win or loose together.
- Or just use 1,2,3 because part of every art is to know when to stop.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others regarding context, but would also add that your incremental scale is important here as well. "Awards" can be given on a 1-5 star rating (think hotels), 0-100% rating (think Rotten Tomatoes movie reviews), or arbitrary (X of X people recommend this restaurant). You may also break it down based on rating by user-type. (critic vs audience, using Rotten Tomatoes again).

Regarding specifically a three-tier system, "Grand Champion", "Reserve Champion", and "Honorable Mention" would be an alternative to Gold/Silver/Bronze.

Answer (score 2):

A martial arts-style belt system would work well in some situations.  This has some nice advantages.

- Many people are familiar with the idea that a white belt is a beginner and a black belt is a master.
- You can include as many intermediate colour levels as you like (sort of; see below).
- You can include other colour theming throughout your site/application to match the user's colour.
- Additional information can be included using, for example, stripes.

---

Responses to O R Mapper's criticisms:

You can't have unlimited colours, but you can have more than the three that bronze/silver/gold allows.  Some martial arts systems only have four or five belts.  Some have more than a dozen (by including stripes as well).

Users wouldn't be expected to memorise a colour list.  In general, brighter colours like yellow come earlier (*nearer to white*), and darker colours like brown come later (*nearer to black*).  This isn't entirely unambiguous but you can easily incorporate feedback to the user like *"only 35 points until blue belt"*.  You can also have a page explaining privileges, [just like here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: How are users supposed to know the order of the other, intermediate colours (without checking on some martial-arts site)? And also, isn't that number somewhat limited? There are only so many colours that you can unambiguously differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

If you go custom, you will most likely need to be based on your brand personality. For example, the company I work for is called Spiceworks and we use a pepper scale based on the scoville heat index to show how much our users have participated in our forum. There are incremental steps they have to take at each level to reach the next pepper level. So they can always see how close they are getting to the next level.

I'm not sure if what you are trying to accomplished is based on incremental steps though. If you are just showing levels of prestige, like gold, silver, platinum, such as with credit cards it might be good just to stick with something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with many of the other answers - ranking is very contextual. Immediate recognition and understanding of the ranking system is completely dependent on the user's background. Star-ratings and gold/silver/bronze are pretty universally recognizable, but for the sake of having another option:

### [*Dan* Rankings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_(rank))

- Ranking system typically split into two tiers ordered from 10 *kyu* (lowest) to 1 *kyu*  at the lower/student tier, and 1 *dan* to 9/10 *dan* (highest) for the higher/master tier
- Fairly recognizable in many East Asian countries and contexts (most esp martial arts)
- Reversal of numerical rankings (10 to 1, then 1 to 10) may be confusing to those unfamiliar, unless system is explicitly laid out
- Examples: Used in [Codewars](http://www.codewars.com/docs) and Go (board game)

Answer (score 1):

This will of course depend heavily on context, but here are some naval progressions.  Note that the names of ship types changed markedly throughout history, so these examples are tied to particular time periods.  Not all of them are military, though most are.

Medieval: Trireme (three rows of oars), Caravel (fore-and-aft rigged), Galleon (large, armed cargo ship).

Napoleonic: Galley (oar powered), Sloop (1 mast), Frigate (2 masts), Ship of the Line (3 masts).

19th Century: Wherry (1 mast), Schooner (two masts), Clipper (3 masts).  These are all cargo ships; the wherry is designed for small navigable rivers.

First World War: Corvette, Destroyer, Cruiser, Battleship, Dreadnought.  In this very specific time-frame, a transition from pre-Dreadnought battleships to battleships which followed the Dreadnought pattern was underway, and the two types were considered distinct.

U-Boats: Type II (small), Type VII (medium), Type IX (large), Type XXI (large, modernised).

Mid 20th Century: Corvette, Frigate, Destroyer, Cruiser, Aircraft Carrier.  From WW2 onwards, the battleship (Dreadnought-type or otherwise) became increasingly irrelevant in terms of actual military achievements.  One or two WW2-era battleships were used for shore bombardments for some considerable time afterwards.

NB: "Battlecruiser" was deliberately omitted from both modern warship lists.  They did not distinguish themselves well in *any* engagement they took part in.

Modern submarines: Submersible (research/civilian), Hunter (searches for Boomers), Boomer (carries nukes).

Modern cargo ships: Tramp (seriously), Oiler, Container, Tanker.

Modern passenger ships: Yacht, Ferry, Cruiser, Catamaran, Liner.

Comment: This is an awesome list. Also the supertankers come to mind, [Panamax ... Triple E](http://people.hofstra.edu/geotrans/eng/ch3en/conc3en/img/containerships.png)

Comment: -1 Interesting categorization of ships, but not an answer widely applicable as a reward system.

Comment: +1 if you showed pictures of the ships it would be easier understandable

Comment: you could do the same with cars planes etc

Answer (score 1):

What about something that actually GROWS!

Baby | Toddler | Adult

Seed | Plant | Flower

Comment: Please don't leave signatures under your post.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just the colors or symbols like : trophies and medals?

*If it's just the color:*
use a color that is bright and when the score gets worse make it fade or darker, or use some other colors

*if its about the object:*
use (what other say before) stars, or just one star that is different filled up!

Answer (score 0):

OK...previous post did not translate well. Try these alternatives...

Some alternatives to Gold, Silver, et al...

- Royal Flush, Four Aces, Full House, Three Jacks
- Diamond (blue), Ruby (red), Emerald (green) Sapphire (yellow or white)
- Home Run, Triple, Double, Single (or HR, Triple Play, Doubleheader, Single)
- General, Major, Captain, Lieutenant
- Rocket, Jetliner, Twin Engine, Bi-Plane, Zepplin?
- Lexus, Mercedes, Cadillac, Lincoln
- Extra Large, Large, Medium, Small

Comment: Same points as with the other. I don't think these references would be clearly and easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Platinum

The current standard ~>
Platinum is greater than Gold is greater than Silver is greater than Bronze.

Comment: hiya! i did say in my question "without using metals" ;)

Comment: @Jimmery +1 good question you asked last year. quite a few answerers have responded, but nowhere did anyone mention platinum. when stackexchange presented your question as an "oldy-goldy, I thought maybe your post will be a useful reference point for those seeking general information on the subject of participant stratification. thx

Answer (score 0):

What about a Pokemon evolution hierarchy, for instance:

- Level 1 : Charmander
- Level 2 : Charmeleon
- Level 3 : Charizard

[image]

And Mew as the ultime level.